# How to calculate values dynamically from Excel table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have a programming issue in Excel that I don't know how to solve it. I want to create an automatic Delivery Cost Program on Excel that will help me calculating the cost more easily.
The input variables are:

- Quantity (Values for 1, 2-9,10-49,50+ and more)
- Shipping method

Depending on the Quantity Value and Shipping method, Excel should lookup on the table and return the total shipping cost according the following Table:

```
------------------------------------------
 Delivery |        Per shipment fee         
------------------------------------------
          |    1     2-9   10-49     50+
------------------------------------------             
Standard  |  2,99   1,89     1,5    1,1
Expedited |  5,99      2    1,75    1,25
Priority  | 10,99   3,39    2,25    1,35
------------------------------------------
```

Let me show you with some examples what I want to get:

1- Example:
    - Quantity: 15
    - Delivery: Expedited
    - Total Cost = 15 * 1,75 = 26,25$

1,75$ is the returned value after looking on the table using the variable Quantity and Shipping Method.

I have tested doing =IF statements but sure that there is an easier way to do it.
I'm not very good on Excel programming so any help will be appreciated

Best regards and have a great day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your table has the delivery types in column `A` in rows 4 through 6 and that the quantities are in row 3 (columns `B` through `E`) the following formula should do it for you:

```
=INDEX(B4:E6,MATCH(B9,A4:A6,0),MATCH(C9,B3:E3,1)) * Quantity
```

Note, that the quantities in row 3 must be a number. So, the numbers should be 1, 2, 10, and 50 and not 1, 2-9, 10-59, 50+. There are two possibilities to achieve that:

1. Create a helper row and hide it (while only showing the row with the "names" as you wish for.
2. Change the number format on these cells: for the column containing the `2` the number format should then be `"2-9"` (custom number format). For the number 10 the number format would be `"10-49"` and the number format for the last column would be `"50+"`. Like this you see what you wan to see while the cells still contain numbers only (for the upper formula to work correctly).

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! It is working properly. I have noticed that the code has commas instead of semi-colon. Is that correct? The gif animation shows semi-colons   =INDEX(B4:E6,MATCH(B9,A4:A6,0),MATCH(C9,B3:E3,1)) * C

Comment: I live in the EU and therefore have the `,` as a decimal placeholder while the `.` is here used for thousands. So, the following would be one million 1.000.000,00 . In order not to confuse Excel formulas here in the EU we have to use `;` for formulas. Otherwise, the following formula wouldn't work: `=Max(1,5;2,5)`. Yet, here (in order to conform to the standard on this site) I am always writing my answers in US style. But I am too lazy to change my regional setting for each screen-cast. So, apologies for that. In the screen-cast you see EU style while the text around it is US style. :)

Comment: OK I see. I have figure it out that maybe was a regional setting issue so I modified to EU myself ;) Thanks again!

Comment: FYI only: all Excel understand your local regional setting and the above posted US setting. If you don't want to convert it manually (next time) then just select any cell and write in the VBE immediate window: `?selection.formula` and you'll get the US-version of your formula. The same way you can use the above formula. Just go onto any cell and then write in the immediate window `selection.formula = "=INDEX(B4:E6,MATCH(B9,A4:A6,0),MATCH(C9,B3:E3,1))"`. Excel will automatically convert the formula to your regional settings and show it as such in the selected cell.